# Draw NFA for regular language

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-identify-if-a-language-is-regular-or-not/) I found a example for a regular language.

L = { a^n   | n>=2 } is regular. Clearly, we can draw a finite automaton with 3 states.

I was asking myself how this graph would look like. If I choose n=11, this means, that the language contains all words with a sequence of 11 a's. This can't be solved with a graph with 3 states, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

given language is L = { a^n | n>=2 }.
here the minimum number of a's is 2, so the finite automata  contains 3 states(2+1)
=>(q0,a)->(q1,a)->(qf,a*).
Similarly if the minimum number of a's required is 11(n>=11),so the finite automata contains 12 states (11+1).
Therefore L = { a^n | n>=11} cannot be solved using 3 states

Answer (score 0):

The given language L cannot be solved using 3 states for your condition i.e, 11a's. For every word to contain a sequence of 11 a's, there should be a minimum of 11 a's. So the graph should contain (11+1)=12 States. Therefore it can't be solved using 3 states.